# Can I make the Display Object in Android by using surface object?

Tags: java, android, linux, mirroring

I want to extract the specific activity's display object for making second screen that is for mirroring. But I can't find information and solve this problem. How can I do this? Could you teach me about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html ?

Comment: yeah, of course saw that. but could you explain this?
I want to background media's screen. What I mean is that I want to use  some interactive activities by my phone and send another media activity to the secondary devices. In this case, Presentation object can obtain the background media's screen Display object? is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

You can use VirtualDisplay in combination with Presentation Object. In android AOSP, in cts/tests/tests/display/.. you can find some implementation example as well.

The api for creating VirtualDisplay is:

> createVirtualDisplay()

Hope this helps.